# How do I import an NPM module without using 'require' or 'import'?

Tags: javascript, npm, import, browserify

I know this is probably a very common and widely answered question. One of the reasons I know it, is because i've spent the last 3 hours figuring out how I shall be importing 3rd party libraries properly in my project which does not support the use of 'import' or 'require'.

It is most likely something very fundamental that i'm missing, but I have reached the point where i'm literally steaming with anger from not being able to find a solution.

So my case ATM:

I am currently working on a wordpress theme built on understrap. I have a dependency on https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber but I have no idea how to include it in my file, and I'm used to working in environments where i can just use import/require from node_modules.

I've read that Browserify could be a solution and i've tried to make it work as a part of gulp, but I eventually just ended up with even more errors than before that were completely gibberish.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "css-element-queries": "^1.2.0",
    "del": "^4.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gulp": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-ignore": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
    "gulp-minify": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-sequence": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1",
    "javascript-detect-element-resize": "^0.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.21",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1",
    "undescores-for-npm": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

**import test**

```
import { getPhoneCode } from 'libphonenumber-js';
$jq(function(){
  console.log(getPhoneCode('GB'));
}
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

and

**require test**

```
var lib = require('libphonenumber-js');
$jq(function(){
  lib.isValidNumberForRegion('23123412', 'GB')
}
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Comment: Where does `getPhoneCode` live? I see no references to it in the repo: https://github.com/ruimarinho/google-libphonenumber/search?q=getPhoneCode&unscoped_q=getPhoneCode

Comment: @lux it most likely doesn't, I just wanted to make some quick examples and my intellisense suggested it. As you can see from the errors the actual problem is the import of node modules, the content doesn't matter.

Comment: And how you are including jquery considering it's sitting in your package.json?

Comment: @lux you should ignore the jquery in package.json, I tried installing it when i tried to get it to work with browserify because it complained about not having jquery. I'm not actually using that anymore, but just using jquery from my individual js files with: var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: you can import js,css into your HTML and include as a script or link

Comment: @Staxaaa but you're not rly supposed to import like this right? <script src="/node_modules/browserify/bundle.js"></script> etc.

Comment: @JonasMohrPedersen https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/google-libphonenumber

Comment: @JonasMohrPedersen, could you accept my answer? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Load the script from unpkg

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/google-libphonenumber@latest"></script>
```

or from a local install

```
<script src="node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js"></script>
```

From there you could see the libphonenumber as a global (in the window object)

Then follow the readme, but adapt it a bit:

```
// Get an instance of `PhoneNumberUtil`.
//const phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
const phoneUtil = libphonenumber.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

// Parse number with country code and keep raw input.
const number = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput('202-456-1414', 'US');

// Print the phone's country code.
console.log(number.getCountryCode());
// => 1

// Print the phone's national number.
console.log(number.getNationalNumber());
// => 2024561414
```

And see '2024561414' in your browser console